# Regular expression that disallows spaces and limits length

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex for following conditions

1) Must be at least 2 characters long
2) Must be no more than 30 characters long
3) Can't contain spaces

So far I found `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,30}$` which does good job at limiting length and not allowing spaces, but it also disallows symbols like `&*` etc, thats should be allowed. Same with emoji i.e.  should be valid for such regex.

Comment: Try `/^\S{2,30}$/`

Comment: Yes, and if you are looking for something more general (since that uses the negative "space" character class):   `/^[^ ]{2,30}$/`

Comment: Not spaces = `[^ ]` 2 to 30 chars = `{2,20}` What problem are you having ?

Comment: @SteveHarris - You're right. Removed my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\S` to match non-space character

```
/^\S{2,30}$/
```

`\S` matches anything other than a space, tab or newline.

**Live Demo:**

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\S{2,30}" />
```

Note that in the HTML5 `pattern` attribute, anchors(`^` and `$`) are implicit.

Comment: Assuming that OP means any white space.

Comment: @PM77-1, then simply solve that by specifying any non-space character `[^ ]`.